# Best Liquid Layout CSS Framework?

Tags: css-frameworks, liquid-layout

Is there an active/solid cross browser css framework on par with blueprint/yui/960 that supports percent based liquid layouts?

I've seen [Emtastic](http://www.dylanbathurst.com/2008/07/27/review-of-emtastic-css-framework-beta-1/), but it [doesn't look like it's been active](http://code.google.com/p/emastic/source/list) for about a year.  What do you think about [Matthew James Taylor's Liquid Layouts](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see this http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/

Answer (score 4):

Blueprint has a "liquid" plugin. Works very well.  [Get it here.](http://www.ixda.org/node/15655)

Answer (score 3):

[Centage!](http://centage.peruste.net/) is my fluid framework built on less.js. It's not thoroughly tested cross browser yet and is in early Alpha state, but check it out!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/) 
It's just not liquid column design, but also include other common design like grid, form, etc.

Answer (score 2):

That's the best one I've seen up to now.
The widest (1140px) and compatibile with mobile and tablets
Link: [1140CS](http://cssgrid.net/)

Comment: Checked this out while browsing this page and just letting everyone know not to use this anymore.
"I’m not comfortable with people continuing to use the framework. It was never really a great solution; just an early experiment that a lot of people participated in. It was a one size fits all, desktop first, templated grid system. In short, not how you should make a responsive website."  Taken from their homepage.